# Select unique/deduplication in SSE/AVX

Tags: algorithm, assembly, sse, simd, avx

**Problem**
Are there any computationally feasible approaches to intra-register deduplication of a set of integers using x86 SIMD instructions?

**Example**
We have a 4-tuple register R1 = {3, 9, 2, 9}, and wish to obtain register R2 = {3, 9, 2, NULL}.

**Restrictions**
*Stablility*. Preservation of the input order is of no significance.

*Output*. However, any removed values/NULLs must be at the beginning and/or end of the register:

- {null, 1, 2, 3} - OK
- {1, 2, null, null} - OK
- {null, 2, null, null} - OK
- {null, 2, null, 1} - Invalid order
- {null, null, null, null} - Invalid output

It is obviously a bonus if it is known to produce one particular output format. Please assume NULL to effectively mean 0 (zero).

*Generality*. Must be able to tolerate the absence of duplicates, and in this case produce an output equivalent to the input register.

*Instruction sets*. I'm looking for solutions for any or all of: SSE2-SSSE3; SSE4.x; AVX-AVX2

Comment: For example, in SSE4 one might be able to iteratively use RMAX = _mm_max_epi32, and conditionally write from RMAX to the output register only if RMAX != RMAX_PREV?

Comment: Assuming this is homework: You should look at the `pshufd` and `pcmpeqd` instructions.

Comment: Haha, no, this is not homework. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Naive solution**

Crude pseudo-code based on the Max() operation. Comments track the data for the first iteration.

```
A = RIN //{3, 9, 2, 9}

For i = 0 .. 3:

  B = Rotate(A, 1) //{9, 2, 9, 3}
  C = Rotate(A, 2) //{2, 9, 3, 9}
  D = Rotate(A, 3) //{9, 3, 9, 2}

  RMAX = Max(A,B) //{9, 9, 9, 9}
  RMAX = Max(RMAX, C) //{9, 9, 9, 9}
  RMAX = Max(RMAX, D) //{9, 9, 9, 9}

  ROUT[i] = RMAX[0] //ROUT = {9, null, null, null}

  TMP  = A
  MASK = Equality(RMAX, TMP) //MASK = {0, 1, 0, 1}
  MASK = Invert(MASK) //MASK = {1, 0, 1, 0}
  Clear(A)
  A = MoveMasked(TMP, MASK) //A = {3, null, 2, null}
```

Some thoughts:

```
A = RIN //{3, 9, 2, 9}

B = Rotate(A, 1) //{9, 2, 9, 3}
C = Rotate(A, 2) //{2, 9, 3, 9}
D = Rotate(A, 3) //{9, 3, 9, 2}

maskA = cmpeq(A,B) //{0,  0,  0,  0}
maskB = cmpeq(A,C) //{0, -1,  0, -1}
maskC = cmpeq(A,D) //{0,  0,  0,  0}

indexA = horSum( { 1,2,4,8 } * maskA ) // 0
indexB = horSum( { 1,2,4,8 } * maskB ) // 10
indexC = horSum( { 1,2,4,8 } * maskC ) // 0

// The problem is this function here
// Of the 4096 possible indexABC only a subset will occur
// Based on an enumeration of all possible indexes a pattern
// for an lookup table could possibly be found
shuffleConst = lookupShuffle( indexA, indexB, indexC )

shuffle(A, shuffleConst)
```

Comment: What does MoveMasked do? If it just moves the masked values, this routine will just remove the maximum value

Comment: For every iteration i, we find the maximum value in A which is stored in RMAX. Then, we compare A and RMAX for equality to create a mask, and then feed TMP back into A, with the maximum value removed. (Updated due to bug - well spotted)

Comment: Ok, I see now. I think instead of the maximum a compare equal could be used. One needs to enumerate all the patterns with duplicate integers and use the masks generated from the comparison to calculate a index, which may be used in a lookup table for shuffle constants.

Comment: Possibly for the lookup table a `pshufb` instruction could be used - if the table is not larger than 16 elements. This way everything would stay in registers. I am not sure if this is feasible.

Comment: I see how we can use Shuffle() as a substitute for Rotate(), but I'm not quite sure how to substitute Max() for Shuffle()? Would you be willing to jot down some pseudo-code? :)

Comment: Interesting! Will toy around with this :)

Comment: In the special case of uint16 values, `phminposuw` (SSE4.1) may give the tournament variant a boost

Comment: You can use `MOVMSKPS`(`int _mm_movemask_ps(__m128 a)`) instruction instead of `horSum(a * b)`. But my feeling is that this problem does not benefit from vector instructions.

Comment: I'm deliberately seeking to avoid branching, as, say, running this over an array would require one branch per element (or element set) in serial code, and might kill the pipeline with mispredictions. Maybe you had something in mind? :)

Answer (score 6):

### Solution

The proposed solution always puts all the unique elements to the lower part of the output, ordered by first occurences. The higher part is zeroed. It is easy to change placing strategy by modifying LUT: put elements to higher part, or reverse their order.

```cpp
static __m128i *const lookup_hash = (__m128i*) &lookup_hash_chars[0][0];
static inline __m128i deduplicate4_ssse3(__m128i abcd) {
    __m128i bcda = _mm_shuffle_epi32(abcd, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 3, 2, 1));
    __m128i cdab = _mm_shuffle_epi32(abcd, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 0, 3, 2));
    uint32_t mask1 = _mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_cmpeq_epi32(abcd, bcda));
    uint32_t mask2 = _mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_cmpeq_epi32(abcd, cdab));
    uint32_t maskFull = (mask2 << 16U) + mask1;
    //Note: minimal perfect hash function here
    uint32_t lutIndex = (maskFull * 0X0044CCCEU) >> 26U;
    __m128i shuf = lookup_hash[lutIndex];
    return _mm_shuffle_epi8(abcd, shuf);
}
```

Full code (with testing) is available [here](http://pastebin.com/B5UxkqzW).

I've also implemented a simple scalar solution by sorting network of 5 comparators, followed by serial comparison of consecutive elements. I was using MSVC2013 on two processors: Core 2 E4700 (Allendale, 2.6 Ghz) and Core i7-3770 (Ivy Bridge, 3.4 Ghz). Here are the timings in seconds for 2^29 calls:

```
// Allendale
SSE:    time =  3.340    // ~16.2 cycles (per call)
Scalar: time = 17.218    // ~83.4 cycles (per call)
// Ivy Bridge
SSE:    time =  1.203    // ~ 7.6 cycles (per call)
Scalar: time = 11.673    // ~73.9 cycles (per call)
```

### Discussion

Note that the result must consist of two types of elements:

1. elements from the input vector,
2. zeros.

However, the necessary shuffling mask is determined at runtime, and in a very complex way. All the SSE instructions can deal only with immediate (i.e. compile-time constant) shuffling masks, except for one. It is `_mm_shuffle_epi8` intrinsic from SSSE3. In order to get shuffling mask quickly, all the masks are stored in a lookup table, indexed by some bitmasks or hashes.

To obtain shuffling mask for a given input vector, it is necessary to collect enough information about equal elements in it. Note that it is fully enough to know which pairs of elements are equal in order to determine how to deduplicate them. If we want to additionally sort them, then we need to know also how the different elements compare to each other, which increases amount of information, and subsequently lookup table. That's why I'll show deduplication **without** sorting here.

So we have four 32-bit elements in an XMM register. They compose six pairs in total. Since we can only compare four elements at a time, we need at least two comparisons. In fact, it is easy to do two XMM comparisons, so that each pair of elements gets compared at least once. After that we can extract 16-bit bitmasks of comparisons by using `_mm_movemask_epi8` and concatenate them into a single 32-bit integer. Note that each 4-bit block would contain same bits for sure, and the last two 4-bit blocks are not necessary (they correspond to excessive comparisons).

Ideally, we need to extract from this bitmask exactly 6 bits located in compile-time known positions. It can be easily achieved with `_pext_u32` intrinsic from BMI2 instruction set. As a result, we have an integer in range *[0..63]* containing 6 bits, each bit shows whether the corresponding pair of elements is equal. Then we load a shuffling mask from precomputed 64-entry lookup table, and shuffle our input vector using `_mm_shuffle_epi8`.

Unfortunately, BMI instructions are quite new (Haswell and later), and I do not have them =) In order to get rid of it, we can try to create a very simple and fast [perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) for all the 64 valid bitmasks (recall that bitmasks are 32-bit). For hash functions in class `f(x) = (a * x) >> (32-b)` it is usually possible to construct a rather small perfect hash, with 2x or 3x memory overhead. Since our case is special, it is possible to construct a minimal perfect hash function, so that the lookup table has minimal 64 entries (i.e. size = 1 KB).

The same algorithm is not feasible for 8 elements (e.g. 16-bit integers in XMM register), because there are 28 pairs of elements, which means that lookup table must contain at least 2^28 entries.

Using this approach for 64-bit elements in a YMM register is also problematic. `_mm256_shuffle_epi8` intrinsic does not help, because it simply performs two separate 128-bit shuffles (never shuffles across lanes). `_mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32` intrinsic performs arbitrary shuffling of 32-bit blocks, but it cannot insert zeros. In order to use it, you'll have to store number of unique elements in LUT too. Then you'll have to put zeros into the higher part of your register manually.

### UPDATE: hash/BMI removed

I have realized that using BMI2 for bit extraction or perfect hash function are not necessary, we can simply use `_mm_movemask_ps` to extract 32-bit masks. This approach may suffer from minor latency issues because we mix INT and FP computations, but it works faster in practice.

```cpp
static __m128i *const lookup_direct_offset = lookup_direct - 0xC0U;
static inline __m128i deduplicate4_ssse3_direct(__m128i abcd) {
    __m128i bcda = _mm_shuffle_epi32(abcd, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 3, 2, 1));
    __m128i cdcd = _mm_shuffle_epi32(abcd, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 2, 3, 2));
    uint32_t mask1 = _mm_movemask_ps(_mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_cmpeq_epi32(abcd, bcda)));
    uint32_t mask2 = _mm_movemask_ps(_mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_cmpeq_epi32(abcd, cdcd)));
    uint32_t maskFull = 16U * mask2 + mask1;
    //Note: use index directly
    uint32_t lutIndex = maskFull;
    __m128i shuf = lookup_direct_offset[lutIndex];
    return _mm_shuffle_epi8(abcd, shuf);
}
```

The [full code](http://pastebin.com/B5UxkqzW) is updated too. This results in minor performance improvement:

```
// Ivy Bridge
new: Time = 1.038   (782827520)    // ~ 6.6 cycles (per call)
old: Time = 1.169   (782827520)    // ~ 7.4 cycles (per call)
```